# Agenda inside header view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-calendars

I'm using https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars and I want to have agenda inside my header view. Something like that:

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1 ,backgroundColor: '#269BB9' }}>
          <CustomHeader {...this.props} />
          <AgendaDiary navigation={this.props.navigation}/>

 </View>
```

AgendaDiary is my agenda. How can I do that. Look that example:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want that any other view like the AgendaDiary inside of the CustomHeader component, you should be able to past the AgendaDiary Component as a Child to the CustomHeader Component. for example

```
<CustomComponent style={styles.anyStyles}>
 <AgendaDiary props={someProps} />
</CustomComponent>
```

Let know if that helps!

Comment: Thank, I tried that but didn't work. I will try again...:)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving some height to the view or wrap AgendaDiary in a view with some height.

See: https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/issues/388